# Overwrite MaterialDrawer's RecyclerView

Tags: android, materialdrawer

According to [this commit](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/commit/a4eaa26eb1be9876c5fd85d330bf935017b7eacc), it is possible to rewrite [drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)'s RecyclerView with a custom one but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can anyone explain to me how to do it properly?

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: you can post a issue on gihub. The library is well maintained and you will get a reply. or try the chat on gitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide any RecyclerView you want with `withRecyclerView()`. This will then be picked instead of the default implementation. Just provide a `RecyclerView` object (which you have retrieved via a `LayoutInflater` or created programmatically) set the `LayoutManager` the `Animator` and everything else you need.

If you are interested what happens in the default behavior follow this link:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/DrawerBuilder.java#L1576

As of your issue. It is also possible to just retrieve the default generated `RecyclerView` after the `Drawer` was built, via `getRecyclerView()`, which will also allow you to adjust some things like `paddings`, and other things. 
See here: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/Drawer.java#L214

As also discussed here:
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/1290